# Conditional question with two conditions in SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am not sure how to write a conditional statement with two conditions but a concise one.

I did well to the conditional statement with one condition, but after that, I could not execute the second condition.

```
  @IBAction func sortButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        let fetchOptions: PHFetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()

        if (self.sortButton.title == "In the past") {
            fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "modificationDate",
                                                             ascending: false)]
            self.fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: assetCollection!, options: fetchOptions )
            self.sortButton.title = "The latest"
        }
    }
```

In the above code, if you tap "sortButtonPressed" named "In the past", the photos in the latest order are updated in the order of the past. But what I would like to do is tap the "The latest" button again to update the photos in the latest order.

Answer (score 0):

```
let fetchOptions: PHFetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
var isDescending = self.sortButton.title == "In the past"
var nextTitle = self.sortButton.title == "In the past" ? "The latest" : "In the past"

fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "modificationDate",
                                                 ascending: isDescending)]
self.fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: assetCollection!, options: fetchOptions )
self.sortButton.title = nextTitle
```

Comment: @bugkr any feedback on this?

Answer (score -1):

Try using a ternary operator
https://syntaxdb.com/ref/swift/ternary

```
@IBAction func sortButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    let fetchOptions: PHFetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()

    fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "modificationDate",
                                    ascending: sender.title == "In the past" ? false : true)]
    self.fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: assetCollection!, options: fetchOptions )
    self.sortButton.title = "The latest"
}
```

Comment: This doesn't update the sort button's title when it's already `"The latest"`.

Answer (score -1):

```
@IBAction func sortButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    let fetchOptions: PHFetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
    let newTitle: String
    let ascending: Bool

    if (self.sortButton.title == "In the past") {
        newTitle = "The latest"
        ascending = false
    } else {
        newTitle = "In the past"
        ascending = true
    }

    fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "modificationDate",
                                                         ascending: ascending)]
    self.fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: assetCollection!, options: fetchOptions )
    self.sortButton.title = newTitle
}
```

Even better would be to assign `"In the past"` and `"The latest"` to constants or enum cases.

Answer (score -1):

You can use switch statement for multiple condition here is my code for understanding with switch statement. also you can use strings with separate constant. so, condition does not miss-match.

```
   let STR_LATEST = "In the past"
   let STR_PAST = "The latest"

    @IBAction func sortButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        switch sender.title {
        case STR_LATEST: buttonTapped(isForLatest: true)
        case STR_PAST: buttonTapped(isForLatest: false)
        default:
            print("Nothing")
        }

    }

    func buttonTapped(isForLatest: Bool) {

        let fetchOptions: PHFetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()

        if isForLatest {

            fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "modificationDate",
                                                             ascending: true)]
            self.fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: assetCollection!, options: fetchOptions )
            self.sortButton.title = STR_PAST

        } else {

            fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "modificationDate",
                                                             ascending: false)]
            self.fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: assetCollection!, options: fetchOptions )
            self.sortButton.title = STR_LATEST

        }
    }
```